# ¿Cómo saber mediante la recursividad en JAVA si un número es perfecto, deficiente o abundante?

Tags: java, recursión

Hasta ahora solo tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class DefiRetr {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    int Num;
    System.out.print("Ingresa un número: ");
    Num = teclado.nextInt();
     DefiRetr objeto = new DefiRetr();
     int res;
         res=objeto.Numerop1R(Num);
    }
public static int Numerop1R(int i) {
    if (i==i){
        int suma;
        suma=Numerop2R(i,1,0);
        if (suma==i){
            System.out.print("El número " + i + " es perfecto");
        }
        return -1;  
    }else{
        return Numerop1R(i);
    }
}
public static int Numerop2R (int i, int j, int suma){
    if(i<=j){
        return suma;
    }else{
        if (i%j==0){
            suma=suma+j;
        }

    }
    return Numerop2R(i,j+1,suma);
}
}
```

Comment: Cuales son los criterios que utilizas para evaluar los números?

Comment: Seria bueno que expliques en que consisten los números que mencionas

Comment: Número perfecto: todo número natural que es igual a la suma de sus divisores propios (es decir, todos sus divisores excepto el propio número). Por ejemplo, 6 es un número perfecto ya que sus divisores propios son 1, 2, y 3 y se cumple que 1+2+3=6. Los números 28, 496 y 8128 también son perfectos. Número abundante: todo número natural que cumple que la suma de sus divisores propios es mayor que el propio número.  Número deficiente: todo número natural que cumple que la suma de sus divisores propios es menor que el propio número.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta, no lo pongas en comentario por favor. Además tienes probabilidad de que te salga un StackOverFlow por la recursividad